# Mathbb in txfonts

Tags: mathbb

I used `txfonts` but I don't like it when I use it with `mathbb`. I like it more when I use Computer Modern instead. And I want to change it to something like Computer Modern. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You should be using newTX rather than the original TX fonts, that have several glitches.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{ABCDEF}$

\end{document}
```

Below the output with the line that “restores” the AMS blackboard bold font and without it for comparison.

### With the `\DeclareMathAlphabet` line (uses AMS bb font)

[image]

### Without the `\DeclareMathAlphabet` line (uses the TX bb font)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, you can load the `\mathbb` alphabet of your choice with

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[
   range={bb,bbit},
   Scale=Matchuppercase]
```

With legacy 8-bit fonts, you can load this and many other math alphabets with `mathalpha`:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}
```

The `\mathbb` alphabet you want is, properly, from the American Mathematical Society’s `amsfonts`, not DEK’s Computer Modern.